# Why BootStrap TokenField input not passed in a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/ to let users select multiple keywords and submit it via post request in Django. Here is what a snippet of code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" />

</head>

<body>
<form action="/lol" method="POST">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" value="red,green,blue" />
<button class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Submit Values</button>
</body>

<script>
    $('#keyword').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
})
</script>
</html>
```

Let's say I fill values in my input text as `red` `green` and `blue` and hit submit. Likely, it should make a `POST` request to `/lol` endpoint and submit the values under `keyword=` param. But it doesn't work.

Is there some issue with Token-Field Library ? How do I make post request of the values user input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a name attribute to the input element. Form elements without a name will not be included in the request.

Following will work,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" id="keyword" value="red,green,blue" />
```

The W3C specification mandates that every form input element have a name attribute specified. Otherwise, that element will not be processed. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)